# DRF - change file field by url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django Rest Framework. I have a Django model with a file field.

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=True, use_url=True)

class MyClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(object):
        model = MyClass
        exclude = []

class MyClassView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = MyClass.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyClassSerializer
```

Take two `MyClass` instances A & B. From my front-end, I'd like to send a PUT request to copy the file of Instance A to model B.

Therefore I first make a GET requests which returns instance A with a file URL (ex: `{..., file: 'http://myserver.com/file.pdf')). I then send a PUT request to update instance B with that URL but I get the following error:

```
The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.
```

For performance reasons I don't want the file to be downloaded and uploaded again. Any idea how to serialize the filed field to make it accept an url of another file on my server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `URLField` in your serializer then in your put request you can send the link instead.

If the file is hosted on your own server and there is a pk available for it, you can use that instead.

Example:

```
class MyClassSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    file_url= URLField(required=True) 

    class Meta:
        model = MyClass
        fields = ('file_url',)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        link = validated_data.get('file_url')
        # and whatever you need to do like download the file or ...
```

Also you can handle the file in your validations and then pass it for update.

Something like this:

```
def validate_file_url(self, value):
    if value:
        #download the file and return it.
    return value
```

Basically anytime you need to do something out of the box, considering adding your own fields and validate them as you wish and use it as you need.

Comment: Thanks, this answers part of my issue. Is there a way to change the `reference to the file` without needing to load the file in memory or download it? I have  only a default filefield (and thus the file name/url), so no pk. Is it worth creating a separate file-model with pk for this purpose ?

Comment: If your file is hosted by your server then yes. you either can save the file path or make a ForeignKey field to the main file. If path is not good enough for you, then yes you can consider making a model to manage your files. It can be useful if you use your files in different models or if you save detailed data like description or ....